# Building a Mobile App With jQuery Mobile, Django, and Phonegap

Tags: django, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am currently starting to build a mobile application using jQuery Mobile and wrap it with Phonegap for native app support, it is an extension to our already existing desktop application written in Django, my question, is what is the best way to connect the client side app written in html5/js/css to the server side, would I just use JSON to send/receive data, and does anyone have any good articles on this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I personally have created multiple native apps with JqueryMobile as my frontend - Django as the server side - and phonegap to natively wrap into a itunes store application. It's really a great combination of technologies that - if done correctly - can yield a fast native application.

First of all you should look into Tastypie. Tastypie is a really easy way to create an instant RESful API that can send JSON data to javascript/JQuery. Its a Django app and it is very pythonic (plenty of easy class/method overrides - everything is transparent).

The flow of data transfer would look something like this:

1. Use a jquery.ajax function or a getJSON function to get/post/put JSON data from a specified URL.
2. This URL is the tastypie API created from your Models. it could look like /api/vi/blogs/all/
3. Now you have JSON data in your frontend with Jquery - you can do whatever you want with it - fill in a table - work with forms - etc.

First Check out some Jquery/Jquery mobile ajax functions and how to work with JSON on the frontend with the Jquery library. Secondly get familiar with sending JSON back to a Django view (parsing the data and saving it to the database). Then dive into the specifics of JQuery Mobile User Interface and the steps to get it working well with PhoneGap.

Comment: Another question I have, is if im using the Django authentication system, and I need users to login how would I achieve this, so when they open the app it prompts them to login once, and they will have the option to remember username/password and keep the user logged in, just wondering what the best way to achieve this is, seeing as how the phonegap app will be client side html/css/js and django will be feeding the JSON data to the app

Comment: Hey - I've done this a few times too. You could SEND JSON back to Django. You have your login form and you collect the username/password from the login form. There are a few ways to go from here. Your action in the submit form can POST the username/password to a django url which will take and compare the username/password in a view function. Your form action might be action=/check-login/  passing the data. You can also do this with ajax - instead of submitting the form - use ajax to send the field data to the same django url/view

Comment: Secondly - in order to keep someone logged in - you can use PhoneGap Local storage to keep data about the user on the device. Save user preferences, etc.

Comment: @HackingLife: Your views looks quite favourable for me as well. But case like in pure django app use `$.ajax({url:'/app/save-user', type:'POST'})` here URL we fetch on dev server like `127.0.0.1:8000/app/save-user` & on production server `https://myappname.com/app/save-user`. So here actual doubt is, How could we access this URL in phonegapp case? as that will be independent of development server.

Answer (score 4):

One of the things you will need to look out for is same-origin features built into jquery. Since  phonegap uses a a webview withl url file:// any web request you make will be cross domain so you need to configure jquery mobile to allow it.

see http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Other than that, there's not much difference between a phonegap mobile application and a regular web app with respect to getting/posting JSON.

Comment: Well Normally, how I would program it is use jQuery mobile to construct my html framework and code that into django templates, and then use django to output the data into those views/templates. So what I was asking, is if JSON is the best approach to that ?

Comment: This isn't correct. When running from the file:// protocol on mobile browsers the CORS is not applied.

Comment: Per the link in my answer "Since jQuery Mobile relies on jQuery core's $.ajax() functionality, $.support.cors must be set to true to tell $.ajax to load cross-domain pages. We've heard reports that webviews on some platforms, like BlackBerry, support cross-domain loading, but that jQuery core incorrectly sets $.support.cors value to false which disables cross-domain $.ajax() requests and will cause the page or assets to fail to load."