# PhoneGap with Django Backend

Tags: ios, django, cordova

I'm working on a web application that uses django.

I would like to create a native application of the site for ios / android using phone gap.

Is this possible? As I understand native devices cannot interpret python code.

It is early in the project and if it proves too difficult I may go with a different framework I.e backbone.js.

Any thoughts / experiences?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's right, you cannot run python code on iOS or Android using PhoneGap, but there is no need to do that. Yes, you can build a native mobile application of your site using PhoneGap.

I'll try to explain a bit how these technologies compare to each other:

- Django is a python web framework running on a web server
- PhoneGap is a framework for building native mobile applications using web technologies (HTML5+CSS+Javascript), the application will run on a mobile device

One common approach is to build the mobile UI with i.e. [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) and use the Django web application to provide a [RESTful API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_APIs) to get data to the application.

Take a look at [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745177/building-a-mobile-app-with-jquery-mobile-django-and-phonegap) for more details.

---

Edit: Answer the question in the first comment

Yes, it's possible to build a fast and well working application with these frameworks. The performance with today's smartphones is more dependent on the quality of the implementation than i.e. jQuery mobile and Django in themselves.

Basically with PhoneGap there are three different ways for showing the content to the user:

- server side generated pages
- pages generated on the client side with Javascript usin data from the server, transferred in a predefined format using for example [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
- a combination of the previous two

[This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171210) clarifies server-client communication and page rendering quite well.

You could use PhoneGap a bit like a constrained web browser, and basically show content directly from your server as you would when the user accesses the site with a normal web browser. **But I don't recommend this**, though. This approach has many downsides to it (i.e. what happens when the user opens a link from your website leading to another website?)

To be accurate, at least in my opinion, UI written with Javascript and running inside an app built with PhoneGap is not native. Comparing native applications and PhoneGap applications is another thing, here is one [take on explaining the differences](http://boagworld.com/mobile-web/mobile-app-vs-mobile-website-design/).

I don't know what kind of service you are building, but in general I'd suggest evaluating the different approaches before starting to build an application. Would a responsive mobile optimized web site do or is there real need for what an app can provide?

If you decide to build an app with PhoneGap, I'd suggest that you do it with client side Javascript and fetch the data from the Django backend with XHR requests in JSON format. There are lots of [examples](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/06/sample-mobile-phonegap-application-with-backbone-js-and-topcoat/) available in the internet.

Comment: Thanks. Would this method yield good performance on mobile? The other thread you linked to suggests so. However I have read varied opinion. I'm trying to wrap my head around what is the difference between visiting the site from a desktop machine compared to mobile? The desktop triggers views via urls - is this the same on mobile? Or is it being suggested that the view logic be written in JavaScript and run natively on the phone for best results? Raising another question.. why does it not run slow on desktop where the server handles the view functions and not the client?

Comment: @eol I updated the answer with answers for your new questions except for the last one which I didn't understand.

Comment: I have taken your advice, and proceeded to build my site using Django with a Tastypie RESTful API to access from my phonegap iOS app. Yet im still really struggling to wrap my head around session authentication when using such APIs. I have detailed my issue(s) [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717875/django-tastypie-request-user-from-js-client-side). I'm hoping you could shed some light to help me wrap my head around this stack. Many thanks in advance. @lekksi

Comment: @eol sorry I've been very busy lately and haven't had the time to help. I'll take a look next week if the question is still unresolved?

Comment: yes still having trouble with this. i have moved to Django RestFramework with slightly more progress. Yet still cant get an ajax token authentication to work with CORS. cannot find a working example anywhere! @lekksi