# Mobile App Architecture: Python as backend to Mobile Apps (Web-based)

Tags: android, python, ios, qt, mobile-webkit

We have just reached some sort of a brick wall in our project and would
appreciate some comments or suggestions or pointers, anything at all.

### Problem Statement

Making a web-technologies (html5/canvas) based mobile/tablet app that can
do some natural language processing.

### Our Constraints

- For UI, we are more reliant on prototyping it with html5 technologies
  like the Canvas api, SVG. It aligns a lot with our skills and has the
  requisite capabilities
- NLP libraries are more mature and well developed in Python (like NLTK)

### Some alternatives that we tried

1. Javascript based libraries for NLP. They might not be as matured, but
   could have proved a faster alternative if there were JS libraries for NLP.

   1. We found these:

      1. Natural https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural
      2. Other JS based libraries:
         http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/node_js_natural_language_nlp
   2. But they proved to be Node based and we couldn't figure out a way
      to add them to a browser kind of page, so that we could embed it into a
      "PhoneGap" type platform. We could be wrong.
2. To use Python NLP logic in our mobile app, we tried some cross
   platform libraries:

   1. PhoneGap http://phonegap.com/

      1. This StackOverflow
         response[PhoneGap with Django Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620711/phonegap-with-django-backend)
         suggests
         that "you cannot run python code on iOS or Android using PhoneGap"
   2. Qt 5 http://qt-project.org/,
      Qt5-mobilehttp://qt.digia.com/qtmobile/

      1. There 2 promising Python Based Qt libraries:
         PyQthttp://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/introand
         PySide http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide
      2. This QML/Python/Qt
         demohttp://qt-project.org/wiki/Using-QtWebKit-and-QML-with-PySideis
         almost exactly what we want:

         1. There is a Python backend with JS calling python objects and
            vice versa using methods like: sendData(), receiveJSON() ...
         2. But it doesn't seem to compile on our machines, and later we
            found PySide development has stagnated and supports only
            till Qt4.8,
            whereas Qt5+ provides support for mobile/tablet development.
      3. This blogpost details how some app developers used Python for
         backend and QML for
         UIhttp://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/03/23/mixd-tv-leveraging-qt-quick-for-a-rich-desktop-ui-from-a-python-back-end/.
         But its just descriptive, and doesn't give real information.
   3. Kivi http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html#:

      1. Despite some niggles, it does seem to work but it doesn't seem
         to have a way to develop a 'UIWebView' class based iOS app,
         which we need
         to use our html5 based UI.
   4. Pythonista http://omz-software.com/pythonista/:

      1. Same problem as Kivi above. We don't want to develop the mobile
         app using Python, we just need a python backend for our html5
         based webapp
   5. iOS: We checked the native iOS development libraries also, but
      couldn't find an easy way to embed a python backend logic
   6. Android: ? Does anyone know if we could embed python into an
      web-based app.
3. AJAX calls to Flask server:

   1. This is the last option, that we are fairly confident about. Host
      python logic on a Flask server and make AJAX calls from the webapp. But
      given its for an application for kids, we might end up making
      numerous AJAX
      calls for same part-of-speech tagging

Any help/suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: My suggestion would be to take the Kivy mobile solution and strip their build process down to *just* Python – i.e. remove all of the Kivy part. Take that and make it visible to PhoneGap via a plugin. (Though personally, I'd go with QML over HTML5 for cross platform mobile apps.)

Comment: Thanks David for responding. We did find this [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/) library though. But like all things `Qt` the documentation is really sparse.

Comment: PythonQt looks nice and clean but it doesn't look like it supports mobile builds? You could perhaps use Kivy's build process to get that piece though. Also, if a QML based application is an option, check this out: http://pyotherside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Wow. This is really interesting. Thanks @DavidK.Hess

Comment: @DavidK.Hess, suppose I want to write a CPython 3.x Android app, with a fairly nice native-app-looking GUI. Could you help explain the reason(s) to strip Kivy out, and replace it with PhoneGap? PhoneGap is developed by Adobe (I'm sure you know). Aren't you worried about the day it's no longer free, closed-source, and has subscription/license costs? I have been under the impression that free and open source, and a  history of use in with Python is generally regarded more popular than more propietary options. Yes, QtPython does look nice for a Windows developer with Visual Studio 2015 IDE.

Comment: That recommendation was really in the context of their particular problem. I personally am not a fan of any HTML5 Hybrid platforms and instead use QML to do cross-platform apps. Unless there is some large amount of Python source code that needs to be leveraged in the mobile app, I would just implement it all in Javascript. While I love and prefer Python, the economics of working with your runtime environment and tooling vs. sticking with a particular language aren't usually worth it.