# Django, phonegap and heroku. How to combine them?

Tags: django, cordova, heroku, django-rest-framework, phonegap-build

I have made a web-app using django framework and stored it on heroku.

How can i combine phonegap so that I will be able to create both iOS and Android application that will simply load my hosted website?

I'm having an hard time knowing how to combine both technologies (django and phonegap) together, because phonegap requires the "index.html"  and i dont know how to make it navigate to my main page.

And i dont know what "Procfile" to use in order that the heroku server will know how to react both.

I have seen somthing involves rest API for django. I found it hard to understand why should i add it for my website...

A tutorial would also be great !!

Answer (score 0):

Integrating phonegap and django is a pretty broad topic covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620711/phonegap-with-django-backend) and in this [tutorial](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/projects/djangogap/).

For setting up multiple stacks on the same heroku app, you will probably want to use [buildpack-multi](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi).